# How to set dynamic title to extended public variable with OOP?

Tags: php, class, dynamic, title

I hope someone can help me. How can I best dynamically change page title, desc, or key vs..vs..by extending the original class? Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
class siteGlobal
    {
        public $arr = array('title'=>'Page Default title','desc'=>'Page default     description');
        public function pageHeader()
            { ?>
<!doctype html><html>
    <?php   }

        public function metaTags()
            { ?>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $this->arr['title'];?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $this->arr['desc'];?>">
   <?php    }

        public function pageBody()
            { ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php    }

        public function pageFooter()
            { ?>
</body>
</html>
    <?php    }
} ?>
```

**OTHER PAGE**

```
require_once('siteGlobal.php');
class pageDetail extends siteGlobal
    {
        public function __construct()
            {
                $this->pageHeader();
                $this->newMetas();
                $this->startBody();     
                $this->sayfaBilgileri();
                $this->pageFooter();
            }

        public function newMetas()
            {
                parent::metaTags();
            }

        public function sayfaBilgileri()
            {
                //HOW I can write a new title and description in this function to siteGlobal.php (public $metaInfo) ?>
<div style="width:640px; margin:0 auto;">
<h1>Page New Title</h1>
<h2>Page New Subtitle</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum, bla bla....</p>
</div>
    <?php    }
    }

$writePage = new pageDetail(); ?>
```

Comment: You can create a setTitle method in the parent class and use it on the extended class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a method in the parent class say:

```
protected function setTitle($title){
    $this->arr['title'] = $title;
}
```

and use it in the extended class this way:

```
parent::setTitle("My title");
```

Comment: Thank's but this function not work, also use default title, not new..

class global